# Add customized JSON Formmter in appsettings.json

Tags: serilog

I created a customized JSON Formatter which extends ITextFormatter
And try to add it to appsetting.json like this:

```
"WriteTo": [
 {
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": {
        "formatter": "CustomizedJSONFormatter"
       // "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog"
    }
  } 
]
```

The default jsonFormatter works fine as shown in the commented line.
But I will get an error if I want to add the customized one:
InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'Serilog.Formatting.ITextFormatter'.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to include the full namespace & assembly.

Comment: I have already tried to add the full name, it has the same issue

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @SLaks, the assembly-qualified type name is required:

```
MyNamespace.CustomizedJsonFormatter, MyAssembly
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be used like below:

```
"WriteTo": [
 {
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": {
       "customFormatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchJsonFormatter,Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch"
    }
  } 
]
```

Comment: I would like to add that it needs a little bit more than that, how i got it work was by replacing the property value on runtime like this 

config["Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:textFormatter"] = typeof(Serilog.Formatting.Compact.RenderedCompactJsonFormatter).AssemblyQualifiedName;

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone else: In my case the following Nuget package was missing, after I have installed it, the error disappeared:

> Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

As @Rodrigo Leite suggested, you do need to reference the Nuget package

> Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch

But also need to change the formatter's path in the appsettings file:

```
"formatter": 
"Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch.ElasticsearchJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Elasticsearch"
```